# Clang: Override all warning and warning-as-error flags specified earlier on the command line

Tags: c++, c, clang

With `gcc` I can throw a bunch of `-Wsome-issue` and `-Werror=other-issue` flags on the command line and the later cancel them all with a single `-w` flag somewhere near the end.

This doesn't appear to be the case with `clang`. A trailing `-w` suppresses some warnings, but not others. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/jfZa58) for an example. I know I can manually disable each warning individually via `-Wno-some-issue` and `-Wno-error=other-issue`, but that's a real pain to manage in the long term.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to cancel all earlier warning flags? Is there a reason why `-w` can suppress some warnings but not others?

Background: My specific use case is a library containing a mix of source files. Some new and some ancient, semi-third-party stuff that we never want to look at, let alone edit. The project has some semi-strict warning flags set globally, but for these few files I'd like to override the global flags and disable all warnings and warnings-as-werrors. In CMake this is done by settings the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property for those files, which appends the given flags after the global flags. With `gcc` this works just fine, but with `clang` it's proving to be a headache.

(And yes I know I could reorganise the project to force those files to be compiled into a separate target, but I was hoping to avoid that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag you need is `-Wno-everything`.

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/33uABD

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't say that's obvious, but it does make sense. Googling around for "Wno-everything" shows very few results, so I guess this isn't a widely known trick. Hopefully others wind up here in the future.